# Jenkins Websphere Deployment doesnt retain application configurations

Tags: websphere, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins version 1.644 and trying to deploy a web application to Websphere 8.5 application server. Jenkins job completed successfully and application is visible through admin console. After the first install, i manually configured Three application configurations namely,
1. Virtual Host
2. Context Root and
3  Modules
after these setup application comes up fine.

Now when i run the Jenkins Job again (option used is Install/Update application), it overrides all the configurations.

Please Let me know how to keep the configurations after each build from Jenkins.

[Websphere Plugin Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQSCK.jpg)

Comment: where do you want to keep the configuration ? if you are deploying same application with another configuration it will override for sure

Comment: Cant we preserve these configurations during every build job update?

Comment: can you provide the steps or url where I can see the steps you are following

Comment: i have configured a job in jenkins, this will use websphere-deploy plugin (for configurations, refer to the link above) and install the app to my server.  After the first install, i got and setup the three configuratons i mentioned above using WAS Admin console.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a build deploy job which will call wsadmin tool and there you can pass parameter in key value pairs

Here is an article which talks about how to build job with parameterized configuration.

http://www.touchdownconsulting.nl/2011/03/building-and-deploying-websphere-applications-with-jenkins-ci/

I have not tried this but looks like it suits your requirement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11382671)

Comment: I agree - Modified the post! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Current Jenkins Websphere deploy plugin (1.3.4)  version does not allow to pass 
 1. Virtual Host 
 2. Context Root and 
 3. Modules

I created a Jython script using AdminApp WAS Utility and updated these parameters

```
AdminApp.edit("appname", ['-MapWebModToVH', [["appname", "appname.war,WEB-INF/web.xml", "api_host"]]])

AdminApp.edit("appname", ['-CtxRootForWebMod', [["appname", "appname.war,WEB-INF/web.xml", "/appname"]]])

AdminApp.edit("appname",['-MapModulesToServers', [["appname","appname.war,WEB-INF/web.xml","WebSphere:cell=appcell01,node=node12v,server=web2+WebSphere:cell=Cell01,node=node11v,server=web1+WebSphere:cell=Cell01,cluster=api-cluster"]]])

AdminConfig.save()
```

Used Jenkins Remote SSH Plugin to invoke this script.